# Dynamic Table view data source

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmanagedobject

Hi I am doing a app in which i use a Dynamic view table, Bit i have a problem with NSManged Objects, can any one find out whats going wrong.

find the code below for your reference.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ([self.controlSelections count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"plainCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    id controlOption = [self.controlSelections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *option = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([controlOption isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        option = (NSString *)controlOption;
        cell.textLabel.text = option;
    }
    else if ([controlOption isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *optionDict = (NSDictionary *)controlOption;
        option = [optionDict valueForKey:self.listKey];
        cell.textLabel.text = option;
    }
    else if ([controlOption isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]])
    {
        NSManagedObject *context=[self NSManagedObject];
        NSManagedObject  *optionData = (NSManagedObject  *)controlOption;
        option = [optionData valueForKey:self.listKey];
        cell.textLabel.text = option;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

the problem is in the following code it is not taking NSMangedObject:

```
else if ([controlOption isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]])
        {
            NSManagedObject *context=[self NSManagedObject];
            NSManagedObject  *optionData = (NSManagedObject  *)controlOption;
            option = [optionData valueForKey:self.listKey];
            cell.textLabel.text = option;
        }
```

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem u r facing?

Comment: It shows a error that 'replace it with NSManagedObjectModel', If i replace it, agin showing error ' Reciever NSManagedObjectModel is a forward class'

Answer (score 1):

## import  in Prefix.pch file

Answer (score 0):

Try  something on these lines -

```
else if ([controlOption isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]])
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[self managedObjectContext]; //I guess you have MOC somewhere.

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[optionData valueForKey:self.listKey] inManagedObjectContext: context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    cell.textLabel.text = [objects objectAtIndex:0]; //for eg   
}
```